# Extrema of the given function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Derermine the extrema of the function $f:R^2->R$
where $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$ under the condition $ \frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: What optimization methods you are familiar with ?  and what didi you try ?

Comment: To ease computation you can very well study $u+v$ under $u^2-v^2=1/2$. You can even reduce to a 1D problem with $u=\pm\sqrt{1/2+v^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=\frac{4a}{2a^2+1}$ and $y=\frac{4a}{2a^2-1}$, then $\frac1x+\frac1y=a$ and $\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{y^2}=\frac12$. Thus, there are no restrictions to $\frac1x+\frac1y$, except that $a\ne\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$.